# What's the difference between a photon and a moving electron?

Tags: electromagnetism

we have a disturbance in the electric field-that is the electron.
we have a disturbance in the electromagnetic field-that is the photon.
but an accelerating electron causes a disturbance in electric and magnetic field
what's the difference between this and an electromagnetic disturbance(photon)?
sorry I am a beginner

Comment: "we have a disturbance in the electric field-that is the electron" incorrect

Comment: In QFT, the electron is a disturbance in the elec**tron** field, not the elec**tric** field.

Answer (score 1):

They are totally different things; and I will be neglecting some depth and nuance in discussing their differences to make it accessible to you (since I don't think you're asking about Fermions vs. Bosons)

Lets first step back and discuss classical light. If you have point charges moving around, or simply oscillating, they will create propagations in Electric and Magnetic fields in the form of waves, these waves move at the speed of light (this is a result of the laws of E&M).

At this point in history people deal with 'charges' not 'electrons', the concept of an 'electron' was not really establishes until much closer to the start of the 20th century. However for the purposes of where you are in Physics, I believe the electron should 'largely' be treated as a point charge (which it is not).

Now if we fast forward to the era of quantum mechanics; experimentation shows us that in fact there is an energy spectrum corresponding to light independent of the power density of its amplitude; in other words there are aspects of the energy held in light and more generally E&M fields which is not explained by classical theory. Enter the 'photon', or as Einstein called them 'quanta of light', which can characterizes light as "wave-packets" of energy, and is able to describe Blackbody Radiation, and Photoelectric Effect.

To answer your question directly; a point charge electron is just a classical point charge, which emits E&M fields corresponding to Maxwell's equations, we can use this to derive the dynamics of light. Photon's are a QM concept that has to do with the quantization of the E&M fields, there is no way to get from Maxwell's equations to photons.

Note: I'm sure as you have heard the electron itself is a Quantum Object, and all that I have said about an electron is actually wrong; although standard in Classical Physics. As it turns out the Quantum Model of the electron can describe all observable "classical" phenomena, and more.

Answer (score 0):

In simplest terms, a photon is an electromagnetic wave packet.  It always moves at the speed of light (in a vacuum), has no “rest mass”, no charge, and a quantum of energy which is proportional to its frequency.  An electron is associated with a wave packet in some other kind of field. It has a (negative) electric charge, can move at any speed (up to c), and has a (nearly) fixed mass at low speeds.